# merging two xml structure for each unique id

Tags: sql-server, xml

Below is the XML file structure and the code that I used to generate it. I have 300 uniq_id rows in table_1. As shown below I only generated for one record i.e uniq_id = 7725. But I would like to generate 300 xml files for these id's. I'm little stumble how to generate them and update these xml files in table_2 which has foreign key uniq_id field. Thanks for your response.

```
  ----------- XML file template -----------
  <Value>
 <Gov_1>
<data>
  <id>radio_option</id>
  <value>7725</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>true</visible>
  </data>
 </Gov_1>
<Gov_2>
<data>
  <id>radioType</id>
  <value>7725</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>true</visible>
  </data>
  </Gov_2>
  </Value>
 ------------------------------------------

 Code that I wrote to generate it.

 ;WITH radio_option AS
  (
       Select 'radio_option' as id, 
        d.uniq_id as value,
        '' as tag,
        'true' as visible,
    FROM table_1 d
    where d.uniq_id = 7725
    ) ,

    radioType AS (
    Select 'radioType' as id, 
         d.uniq_id as value,
         '' as tag,
         'true' as visible,
          d.uniq_id
         FROM table_1 d
         where d.uniq_id = 7725
    )

     select 
         ( 
           select t1.id, t1.value, t1.tag, t1.visible
           from radio_option t1
           FOR XML PATH('data'),ROOT('Gov_1'), TYPE ),

         (
          select t2.id, t2.value, t2.tag, t2.visible
          from radioType t2
          FOR XML PATH('data'),ROOT('Gov_2'), TYPE
  )
  FOR XML PATH('Value')



   ----------
   Table 1 (
   uniq_id int, (pk)
   add_name varchar(150), 
   contact_name varchar(150),
   location varchar(150),
   company name varchar(150),
   date_t datetime 
   ) 

   Table 2
   ( 
    table_2_rid int,
    uniq_id int (fK),
    perm_id int,
    add_id int,
    Xml_file xml,
    date_t, datetime
    )

 Table 1
 uniq_id    add_name    contact_name    location    company_name    date_t
   7725      abcd        Victor           CA          XYZ          8/7/2016
   7726      dfre        Angelic          FL          FHT          8/7/2016

 Table 2
table_2_rid uniq_id perm_id  add_id    Xml_file         date_t
     1      7725     3847     2345     xml_file_7725    8/7/2016
     2      7726     4578     5432     xml_file_7726    8/7/2016
```

Comment: please, add table defenition and sample data

Comment: hey, I added the table definition and some sample data. Hope it helps. Thanks for your response.